# kubectl command showing empty

Tags: kubernetes, cron, kubectl

I have a use case in which I need to run `kubectl` command in `crontab`. I am getting empty response from all `kubectl` commands

I have tried this

```
#!/bin/sh

/usr/bin/kubectl get po >> /cron.txt
```

Help will be appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure you have pods running in the default namespace? Try `-A` to include all namespaces. kubectl uses config from ~/.kube/config, which is user-specific

Comment: Yes. When I run shell file manually. It gives the required output. But when I run through cron it doest do anything

Comment: did you try to call this file on crontab like: `bash script.sh`?

Comment: `* * * * * /bin/sh /script.sh` Other things are working on this file, but not kubectl

Comment: I have tried kubectl version in the shell file, and it is only showing client version
`/usr/bin/kubectl version >> /cron.txt`, but when I run script file manually, it is showing me both versions (client / server). Looks like while running through cron it is not accessing server. Although I have also tried to set KUBECONFIG variable, but of no use

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you're not getting any output, but I think I know why it's not telling you why it's not getting output.

Your command line is only going to get stdout, and drop stderr on the floor. It's likely that stderr will tell you why it's not working.

Try changing the command line to:

```
/usr/bin/kubectl get po 2>&1 >> /cron.txt
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried. But of no use. I have tried setting up KUBECONFIG variable but issue is the same

Comment: I have tried kubectl version in the shell file, and it is only showing client version `/usr/bin/kubectl version >> /cron.txt`, but when I run script file manually, it is showing me both versions (client / server). Looks like while running through cron it is not accessing server. Although I have also tried to set KUBECONFIG variable, but of no use

Comment: When a cron job runs, it does not run as you, it runs as root. https://serverfault.com/questions/247043/what-user-do-scripts-in-the-cron-folders-run-as-i-e-cron-daily-cron-hourly

Answer (score 0):

Since you've tried running it using `bash` and `sh`, the problem is because the `~/.kube/config` is in your `home`.

If you are adding a Cron via `crontab -e`, you are adding a cron to the `root` user and `root` doesn't have the `~/.kube/config` in its `home`.

There are a few ways to fix your problem, see which one is better to you:

- You can copy the file from `~/.kube/config` to `/root/.kube/config` if for some reason you need to run it using `root` user, but it is not a good practice.
- You can set an env var like `$KUBECONFIG` and export the file location to the whole system. Take a look on [configure-access-multiple-clusters/#linux-1](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/#linux-1).
- You can also set up a `contrab` and force your user to run it, to do that you need to *edit/create* a file in `/etc/cron.d/` and pass the username like:

.

```
0 7 * * * username /usr/bin/kubectl get po >> ~/cron.txt
```

Let me know if you have any questions.